# SP2-0606: Cannot create SPOOL file

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I use Oracle 12c R2 on Windows 10 pro x64. I get sample script by

```
cd E:\github.com\oracle
git clone https://github.com/oracle/db-sample-schemas.git
```

in CMD

```
E:\github.com\oracle\db-sample-schemas\human_resources>sqlplus sys/summer as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on Wed Jun 28 11:15:24 2017

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Advanced Analytics and Real Application Testing options

SQL> @hr_main.sql

specify password for HR as parameter 1:
Enter value for 1: 123456

specify default tablespeace for HR as parameter 2:
Enter value for 2: hr_tablespace

specify temporary tablespace for HR as parameter 3:
Enter value for 3: hr_temp_tablespace

specify password for SYS as parameter 4:
Enter value for 4: summer

specify log path as parameter 5:
Enter value for 5: C:\vy\

specify connect string as parameter 6:
Enter value for 6: localhost:1521/orcl

SP2-0606: Cannot create SPOOL file "C:\vy\hr_main.log"
DROP USER hr CASCADE
          *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01918: user 'HR' does not exist


CREATE USER hr IDENTIFIED BY 123456
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-65096: invalid common user or role name


ALTER USER hr DEFAULT TABLESPACE hr_tablespace
           *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01918: user 'HR' does not exist


ALTER USER hr TEMPORARY TABLESPACE hr_temp_tablespace
           *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01918: user 'HR' does not exist


GRANT CREATE SESSION, CREATE VIEW, ALTER SESSION, CREATE SEQUENCE TO hr
                                                                     *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01917: user or role 'HR' does not exist


GRANT CREATE SYNONYM, CREATE DATABASE LINK, RESOURCE , UNLIMITED TABLESPACE TO hr
                                                                               *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01917: user or role 'HR' does not exist


ERROR:
ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect
descriptor


Warning: You are no longer connected to ORACLE.
SP2-0640: Not connected
ERROR:
ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect
descriptor


SP2-0640: Not connected
SP2-0640: Not connected
SP2-0310: unable to open file "E:\github.com\oracle\db-sample-schemas\human_resources\human_resources\hr_cre.sql"
SP2-0310: unable to open file "E:\github.com\oracle\db-sample-schemas\human_resources\human_resources\hr_popul.sql"
SP2-0310: unable to open file "E:\github.com\oracle\db-sample-schemas\human_resources\human_resources\\hr_idx.sql"
SP2-0310: unable to open file "E:\github.com\oracle\db-sample-schemas\human_resources\human_resources\\hr_code.sql"
SP2-0310: unable to open file "E:\github.com\oracle\db-sample-schemas\human_resources\human_resources\\hr_comnt.sql"
SP2-0310: unable to open file "E:\github.com\oracle\db-sample-schemas\human_resources\human_resources\\hr_analz.sql"
not spooling currently
SQL>
```

How to fix these error:

```
SP2-0606: Cannot create SPOOL file
ORA-01918: user 'HR' does not exist
ORA-65096: invalid common user or role name
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easy ones first:

> ORA-01918: user 'HR' does not exist

The script starts with a precautionary `drop user` statement. You haven't run the script before so there is no HR user to drop. Hence the message. You can ignore it.

> ORA-65096: invalid common user or role name

You have given an invalid password: `Enter value for 1: 123456`. For whatever reasons Oracle passwords follow similar rules to object names, which means the password must start with a letter - unless it's wrapped in double-quotes.

Now this is a trickier issue:

> SP2-0606: Cannot create SPOOL file

So, does directory `C:\vy` exist? Does your user have write access to it?

Comment: Please help me next steps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44798174/error-when-run-oracle-database-sample-schema-script

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue.

You need create HR user before runnig "hr_main.sql". Follow next steps::

**SQL> connect sys as sysdba**

Enter password:

Connected.

**SQL> create user HR identified by oracle;**

User created.

**SQL> @?/demo/schema/human_resources/hr_main.sql**

and next step as in guide:
https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/COMSC/installation.htm#COMSC109

Answer (score 0):

SP2-0606: Cannot create SPOOL file "E:\output.txt"
---- this error is occur because of permission (that mean you don't have permission to write on this drive) you can only read . so try to write on desktop drive . so copy the complete desktop path.
spool C:\Users\james\OneDrive\Desktop\output.txt --- it work for me